# Android autoTesting with Cucumber and Espresso

Tags: android, cucumber, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a problem with Cucumber, I can't start tests, all the time I have the same problem, and have no idea how to fix it.

When I run tests I got this message:

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'cucumber.runtime.CucumberException'
Empty test suite.
```

My build.gradle

```
android {
....
sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {...
//Testing
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.4') {
    exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    exclude module: 'guava'
}
androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3'
```

Cucumber Runner:

```
CucumberOptions(features = "features/Test.feature")
public class CucumberInstrumentationRunner extends MonitoringInstrumentation {

    private final CucumberInstrumentationCore instrumentationCore = new CucumberInstrumentationCore(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        instrumentationCore.create(bundle);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        waitForIdleSync();
        instrumentationCore.start();
    }
}
```

Test.feature

```
Scenario: Пользователь пытается авторизоваться используя неверные логин и пароль
Given I've launched "com.example.activities.LoginActivity"
When User 'User@User.com' singIn with password 'wrongPassword'
Then Check message about incorrect password
```

and LoginActivitySteps

```
public class LoginActivitySteps extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    // ViewInteractions

    private final ViewInteraction mEmailEdt = onView(withId(R.id.edt_email));
    private final ViewInteraction mPassEdt = onView(withId(R.id.edt_pass));
    private final ViewInteraction mLoginBtn = onView(withId(R.id.button_login));

    private Activity currentActivity;

    @Given("^I've launched \"([^\"]*)\"$")

    public void I_ve_launched_(String activityClassName)
            throws Throwable {
        String targetPackage = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName();
        Class<? extends Activity> activityClass =
                (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(activityClassName);

        currentActivity = launchActivity(targetPackage, activityClass, null);
    }

    @When("^User '(.+)'  singIn with password '(.+)'$")
    public void userLogin(String login, String password) {
        mEmailEdt.perform(clearText());
        mPassEdt.perform(clearText());
        mEmailEdt.perform(ViewActions.typeText(login));
        mPassEdt.perform(ViewActions.typeText(password));
        mLoginBtn.perform(ViewActions.click());
    }

    @Then("^Check message about incorrect password")
    public void checkTextOnScreen() {
            onView(withText("Wrong pass")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing some `build.gradle` configuration parts like:

```
    testApplicationId "cucumber.cukeulator.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "cucumber.cukeulator.test.Instrumentation"
```

Check this `Cucumber` example `build.gradle` configuration content:  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/android/android-studio/Cukeulator/app/build.gradle

Hope it will help